# Java WebService on Tomcat with HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) on rest services with Java. I reached the step where I run the service but I always get `HTTP Status 404`. I searched for my issue but can't seem to get it to work.

I am calling the service with this url `http://localhost:8080/FirstWebService/rest/hello`.

Below is the `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>FirstWebService</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>first.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and `Hello.java` is below:

```
package first.webservice;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><hello>Hello Jersey</hello>";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html><title>Hello Jersey</title><body><h1>Hello Jersey</h1></body></html>";
    }
}
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: you are calling the wrong URL

Comment: I am calling this `http://localhost:8080/FirstWebService/rest/hello`

Comment: if you deviate from a tutorial you should know what you are doing

Comment: The only deviation is the context root and the package name

Comment: "display-name" is only informative : it's not in the url

Comment: The context root I'm using is from the `Web Project Settings` of the project properties in Eclipse.

Comment: In fairness the tutorial does mark multiple variables with the same name, which can be confusing since it introduces ambiguity. Check the context root in Tomcat if you can reach the configuration or logs.

Comment: @ewhoch How do I check the context root in Tomcat?

Comment: When I open the Tomcat server, and go to `modules` tab, there is `Path` column which has `/FirstWebService` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try @Path("hello"), i.e. without the slash

Comment: That did it.
I am wondering why was this the issue? In the tutorial I mentioned the `/` was there

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 caused when Tomcat is not able to find the required file path. The directory structure for adding your project should be as following:

$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/Your-Project/(jsp or html files)
$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/Your-Project/WEB-INF/classes (Your all java cleasses)
$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/Your-Project/WEB-INF/lib (All project libraries here)
$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/Your-Project/WEB-INF/web.xml (Your deployment descriptor)

To access your project files you can call it as: (in your case)
`http://localhost:8080/rest/hello` because you mapped your class as 
`<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` in your deployment descriptor (web.xml)

Cheers!!

Comment: The thing is my project is deployed on `wtpwebapps` (the default deployment path) not `webapps`. Should it be `webapps`?